# How to send an email from Windows 7.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, iis, smtp

I have Windows 7.0 Enterprise and I've installed Remote Server Administration Tools from http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=7887

I have also configured my IIS to use Localhost as SMTP Server: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753146(v=ws.10).aspx

```
var smtpSender = new SmtpSender("localhost");
smtpSender.UserName = this._emailAccount.EmailAddress;
smtpSender.Password = this._emailAccount.Password;

smtpSender.Send(fromEmail, 
  toEmail,
  subject,
  body);
```

but when I try to send email, it throws the below exception:

```
An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 127.0.0.1:25
```

I've seen other posts that says I should be installing a new SMTP Server but I've installed Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows 7.0. Doesn't it enclude SMTP Server?

Installing the Remote Server Administration Tools only adds a new snap-in to the IIS apparently and doesn't install any SMTP server locally?

Comment: Do your IIS websites have a `SMTP E-mail` option in the ASP.NET configuration area? Are you sure that the Firewall is not blocking some ports SMTP uses? Can't help you with Remote Server Administration Tools part, I have always added SMTP Server from the Add Features/Roles section.

Comment: I'm using Web Development Server now so it's not even hosted/deployed unto IIS yet. I'm suspecting it's highly likely to be a firewall issue.